# Dropping all rows in pandas having same values in one column and different values in another

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following type of dataframe:

```
   col1 col2
0   123    a
1   123    a
2   123    a
3   123    b
4   345    a
5   345    c
6   456    d
7   456    d
8   678    e
9   897    f
```

For a particular repeated value in `col1`, ALL the corresponding `col2` values should be exactly the same. If even one of the corresponding `col2` values is different, all instances of that `col1` value are dropped. So in the above example, all rows having `123` in `col1` are dropped because there's one `b` that's different from the `a`'s.

Rows corresponding to unique values in `col1` are retained. Finally, out of all the repeated values in `col1` (provided all of them have the same corresponding `col2` value), only one is retained. So the output would be:

```
   col1 col2
6   456    d
8   678    e
9   897    f
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this without using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `subset` and `keep` parameters when searching for duplicates in a DataFrame.

sample:

```py
# make df
data = zip([123, 123, 123, 123, 345, 345, 456, 456, 678, 897], 
           ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['col1', 'col2'])

# dedupe
df.drop_duplicates().drop_duplicates(subset=['col1'], keep=False)

# output
#   col1 col2
# 6  456    d
# 8  678    e
# 9  897    f
```

The first `.drop_duplicates()` keeps the first instance of each unique row. The second drops any rows with the same value for `col1` regardless of `col2` (keeping none of them). Because we're only dealing with unique rows at this point, the `.drop_duplicates(subset=['col1'], keep=False)` necessarily drops only rows with duplicated `col1` values and distinct `col2` values

Answer (score 2):

IIUC `groupby` with `nunique` then we do `isin` + `drop_duplicates`

```
s=df.groupby('col1').col2.nunique().ne(1)
yourdf=df.loc[~df.col1.isin(s.index[s]),:].drop_duplicates()
yourdf
Out[974]: 
   col1 col2
6   456    d
8   678    e
9   897    f
```

Comment: Good one +1, can use `transform` instead of `isin`: `df[df.groupby(['col1']).col2.transform('nunique').eq(1)]`.

Comment: @QuangHoang ah , just want to try something diff :-)